# Winrt advanced scroll viewer content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I have the need to make a control that allows for multi directional scrolling, but only for specific elements within the scollviewer.

Something like this:
[image: Multi directional scrolling]
The control is split into 4 parts.

Top left is a static header, it will not move when scrolling.
Bottom left works like a listbox, only scrolls up and down.
Bottom right can scroll in all directions but needs to be in sync with the scrolling of the bottom left area.
Top right is the header for the content in the bottom right, and must be in sync as well.

There is an app on the Windows Store now called Project Timeline, and it appears they have done this with 1 ScrollViewer, but im not entirely sure how.

I've implemented a solution with 2 scrollviewers, but between the 2 scrollviewers there is scroll tearing on slower devices, and this is unacceptable.

Anyone have any ideas how this can be done with 1 scrollviewer?

PS, I'm looking for a XAML solution, not a WinJS solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for days, didnt find anything, then as soon as I post this question i figure it out... typical right?

This is accomplished with:

```
ScrollViewer.TopLeftHeader
ScrollViewer.TopHeader
ScrollViewer.LeftHeader
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.topleftheader